# Adding header script to an html page using php "required" from a different page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a template.html page that has a header <>and body <>. By default the html header doesnt have anything in it. However, from a php page, i would like to require the html page and add script to the header of the html page. The following is an example.

<<<.?php
    /require("index.html");

```
echo "
     <header>
            <script>

            </script>

     </header>
 ";
```

?.>>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be the easiest way. Change your include file to include string. If that string is defined, include it in the header.

```
<php

$script = "<script src='myfile'></script>";
include("header.php");

?>
```

PHP Include File

```
<html>
<head>
...
// if $script is defined, include it
<?php if( isset($script) ){ echo $script; } ?>
</head>
```